# Replace value in dataframe column, if other 'better' value exists elsewhere

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe structured roughly as follows (it's a list of event participants; the pool is small enough that we can assume that a repeating value refers to the same person):

```
id_1 id_2 id_3 ... year  name   country
1_c  2_a  3_a      2011  John   France
1_b  2_a  3_c      2010  Jill   UK
1_c  2_b  3_c      2018  John   Germany
1_c  2_b  3_c      2014  Jason  Italy
1_c  2_b  3_b      2017  John   Unknown
```

The aim is to replace the 'Unknown' values with the a country name, if that person has a known country from their participation in another year.

In the extremely unlikely event that they're listed under different countries in different years, I'm happy to just tag them under whichever country they were listed under in the year closest to the 'Unknown' year (so above, we would change 'Unknown' to 'Germany' for John).

I'm a complete pandas (and python!) novice. I've created a list of unique name/country pairs using drop_duplicates, but I'm assuming there must be a much more elegant way to do the rest than the mess of list, tuple and dict conversions I'm currently knee deep in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One *non-vectorised* solution is possible via [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). This is just a thinly veiled loop. We cycle through each row. If the country is unknown we:

- Filter for `country` not equal to "Unknown" and `name` equal to row name.
- Calculate absolute difference between each year with row year for this subset.
- Retrieve `country` for the minimum absolute year difference.

Here's a complete example:

```
def get_country(row):
    if row['country'] != 'Unknown':
        return row['country']
    else:
        res = df.loc[(df['country'] != 'Unknown') & (df['name'] == row['name'])]\
                .assign(year_diff=(df['year']-row['year']).abs())
        return res.loc[res['year_diff'].idxmin(), 'country'] if not res.empty else 'Unknown'

df['country'] = df.apply(get_country, axis=1)

print(df)

  id_1 id_2 id_3  year   name  country
0  1_c  2_a  3_a  2011   John   France
1  1_b  2_a  3_c  2010   Jill       UK
2  1_c  2_b  3_c  2018   John  Germany
3  1_c  2_b  3_c  2014  Jason    Italy
4  1_c  2_b  3_b  2017   John  Germany
```

There will certainly be clever ways to optimise using Pandas / NumPy, for example via sorting. If performance is a concern, you should consider an alternative algorithm.

Comment: Thank you, this is so much cleaner than what I had! 

I can't seem to apply it though, as df is coming up as unresolved and apply can only take one parameter? I'm creating the df after doing a data scrape, so I'm not currently able to declare it before main. Should I dump this into a separate script or is there another solution?

Comment: @banbourg, Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "df is coming up as unresolved". This answer assumes you have a dataframe as in your question. If your real dataframe is different, then you can try updating your question and I may be able to help.

Comment: Sorry, I appreciate this is probably super basic - I mean that the dataframe is created and populated in main(), currently (from a web scrape). So when I add the function declaration you provided to the top of my script file, I get a NameError  ("global name 'df' is not defined", u'occurred at index 0'). Do I just need to declare it as an empty variable beforehand? Or run get_country in a separate script where I can load up the df from a csv, before main?

Comment: @banbourg, I can't tell. You may have to ask a separate question. Your dataframe must be stored in a variable. I call it `df`, yours can be called `my_dataframe`. Just change the name accordingly. This seems more a question of how to structure your code rather than manipulate data.

Comment: Problem solved: I didn't realise you could define functions inside others in python (so here, I can define get_country() inside main() once my df variable exists). D'oh! Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility. I think it might still be on the slow side because of the apply, but perhaps faster if you have a small number of unique 'name's compared to the number of rows:

- Replace `Unknown` with np.NaN
- Sort the DataFrame and set the index to 'year'
- We'll create a dictionary that maps all of the strings in 'country' to a numeric value.
- This allows you to then use `pd.Series.interpolate(method='nearest')`

  - Need to throw in a few cases to fill properly if it's the first entry, or last entry and to avoid errors if everything is `NaN`
- After interpolation, map the values back.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = df.replace('Unknown', np.NaN)
df = df.sort_values(['name', 'year']).set_index('year')

dct = dict(zip(df.country[df.country.notnull()].unique(), 
               range(df.country[df.country.notnull()].nunique())))
inv_dct = {v: k for k, v in dct.items()}
df['country'] = df['country'].map(dct)

df['country'] = df.groupby('name')['country'].apply(
                   lambda x: x.interpolate(method='nearest').bfill().ffill()
                             if x.notnull().sum() > 1 else x.bfill().ffill())

df['country'] = df['country'].map(inv_dct)
```

Output:

```
     id_1 id_2 id_3   name  country
year                               
2014  1_c  2_b  3_c  Jason    Italy
2010  1_b  2_a  3_c   Jill       UK
2011  1_c  2_a  3_a   John   France
2017  1_c  2_b  3_b   John  Germany
2018  1_c  2_b  3_c   John  Germany
```